# MediaStream to C++ data type conversion

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ffmpeg, webrtc, google-nativeclient

I am sending a video and audio stream to C++ from Google Chrome, I am not sure how to cast the data.

What is the data type of this and how do I convert it to C++?

`videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0]`

I want to build ffmpeg encoder using C++ but I can not figure out how to cast this type?

I was also wondering if there is method to build a test case similar to this data type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome native messaging: can I stream a MediaStream to a native program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569765/chrome-native-messaging-can-i-stream-a-mediastream-to-a-native-program)

Comment: @wOxxOm it is not a duplicate, I managed to get the frames when I am not using PPAPI_Simple. when I migrated the code to use PPAPI_Simple it did not work.

I want to figure out how to make the communications via threads, I could not find it in the documentation.

It is connected to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934011/collecting-frames-of-mediastream-with-ppapi-simple